# added Scroll event to ListView, and mouse wheel moves it, but scroll event doesn't file

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I have added this

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Scrolled;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        const int wm_vscroll = 0x115;
        if (m.Msg == wm_vscroll && Scrolled != null)
        {
            Scrolled(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

and when i scroll the mouse wheel it scroll the list perfectly, my scroll event doesn't fire.

I have tried hooking MouseWheel, but the scroll happens after the mousewheel event returns to windows, but still doesn't call Scroll event.

EDIT:-
I have added an OnMouseWheel event that calls my update code, but this is called before the visible area is scrolled, so my update code misses some parts.

I want the mousewheel event to scroll the visible area then call the onScroll event, 
OR
for the onscroll event to get called as a by product of the mousewheel scrolling the visible area

Comment: Edit added to explain mousewheel not working

Answer (score 0):

Trapping WM_MOUSEWHEEL worked for me:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{

    private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20a;

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Scrolled;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL && Scrolled != null)
        {
            Scrolled(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

default listview's visual tree have  ScrollViewer control.
ScrollViewer override OnMouseWheel  and set e.handled = true,
if you want to handle this event, you must use EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(Type classType,    RoutedEvent routedEvent,Delegate handler,true);
true to invoke this class handler even if arguments of the routed event have been marked as handled; 
try it:

```
class CustomListView: ListView
{
    public CustomListView()
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(CustomListView), MouseWheelEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnMouseWheel), true);
    }
    internal static void OnMouseWheel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something you want
    }
}
```